# AWS RDS host instance creation fails: "hardware error"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a MySQL RDS host instance on AWS (via Ansible) and getting the following error:

```
The database instance has been put into STORAGE_FAILURE due to a hardware failure
```

It happens after about 2 hours of saying it's in a "Creating" state. It fails whether or not we specify multi-AZ.

Other specs:

- Type: db.t2.large
- MySQL version: 5.6.27
- Encrypted: yes
- Tenancy: dedicated
- Storage: 100 GB

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: Sounds like something for AWS Support. If you're paying $1500/month for dedicated instances surely you've got at least the $50/month support plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that for dedicated tenancy, the RDS instance class has to correspond to the EC2 instance class, e.g. `m3.medium` EC2 corresponds to `db.m3.medium`. I was using `m3.medium` with `db.t2.large`.

Makes sense, but it's kinda buried in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html?shortFooter=true).